# How to receive gesture events on a QGraphicsItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I already set:

```
graphicsView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
graphicsView->viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
graphicsView->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
graphicsView->viewport()->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
```

And I’m still unable to receive gestures on the `sceneEvent` method of a `QGraphicsItem` using Qt 5.1, does anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to solve this problem: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32600/